# What exactly does it mean when Chrome reports 'no certificate transparency information was supplied by the server?'

Tags: certificates, chrome

When visiting Gmail in Chrome, if I click on the lock icon in the address bar and go to the connection tab, I receive a message 'no certificate transparency information was supplied by the server' (before Chrome 45, the message was displayed as 'the identity of this website has been verified by Google Internet Authority G2 but does not have public audit records').

What exactly does it mean that the certificate does not have public audit records?  Are their certain threats a site using a certificate without public audit records has that a site using a certificate with public audit records does not?

[image: Examples of the message as of Chrome 45 and before Chrome 45]

Comment: I see you had to take a screenshot to export the message. If you think it should be easier to copy the connection  information out of Chrome, vote for https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=254249

Comment: Has anyone found an example *with* public audit records?

Comment: For an example *with* public audit records, see https://embed.ct.digicert.com/ . It's a purpose test site. Perhaps we'll see transparency proofs on real sites (most likely Google and Twitter) next year.

Comment: Update February 2015: twitter.com is now "publicly auditable" in Chrome. You'll see a link "transparency information" to open a dialog  "signed certificate timestamps viewer".

Answer (score 151, accepted):

***Note***: If you're here because your certificate isn't trusted by Chrome, this is not the reason. Chrome will still trust certificates without CT information. If your certificate isn't trusted, there is an additional factor that you may have missed.

[image: Comparison of auditable versus no audit record]

This has to do with the concept of [Certificate Transparency](http://www.certificate-transparency.org/what-is-ct).

## The Problem

Browsers currently trust certificates if four conditions are met: (a) the certificate is signed by a trusted CA, (b) the current time is within the valid period of the certificate and signing certs (between the `notBefore` and `notAfter` times), (c) neither the certificate nor any signing certificate has been revoked, and finally, (d) the certificate matches the domain name of the desired URL.

But these rules leave the door open to abuse. A trusted CA can still issue certificates to people who shouldn't have them. This includes compromised CAs (like [DigiNotar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiNotar)) and also CAs like [Trustwave](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/02/14/trustwave_analysis/) who issued at least one intermediate signing certificate for use in performing man-in-the-middle interception of SSL traffic. A curated history of CA failures can be found at CAcert's [History of Risks & Threat Events to CAs and PKI](http://wiki.cacert.org/Risk/History).

A key problem here is that CAs issue these certificates in secret. You won't know that Trustwave or DigiNotar has issued a fraudulent certificate until you actually *see* the certificate, in which case you're probably the perpetrator's target, not someone who can actually do any real auditing.  In order prevent abuse or mistakes, we need CAs to make the history of certificates they sign *public*.

## The Solution

The way we deal with this is to create a log of issued certificates. This can be maintained by the issuer or it can be maintained by someone else. But the important point is that (a) the log can't be edited, you can only *append* new entries, and (b) the *time* that a certificate is added to the log is verified through proper timestamping. Everything is, of course, cryptographically assured to prevent tampering, and the public can watch the contents of the log looking to see if a certificate is issued for a domain they know it shouldn't have.

If your browser then sees a certificate that *should be* in the log but isn't, or that is in the log but something doesn't match (e.g. the wrong timestamp, etc), then the browser can take appropriate action.

What you're looking at in Chrome, then, is an indication as to whether a publicly audible log exists for the certificate you're looking at. If it does, Chrome can also check to see whether the appropriate log entry has been made and when.

## How widely is it used?

Google maintains a list of "known logs" [on their site](http://www.certificate-transparency.org/known-logs). As of this writing, there are logs maintained by Google, Digicert, Izenpe, and Certly, each of which can maintain the audit trail for any number of CAs.

The Chrome team [has indicated](http://www.certificate-transparency.org/ev-ct-plan) that EV certificates issued after 1 Jan 2015 must all have a public audit trail to be considered EV. And after the experience gained dealing with EV certificate audit logs has been applied, they'll continue the rollout to all certificate issuers.

## How to check the logs

Google added a Certificate Transparency lookup form to their standard Transparency Report, which means you can now query for the domains you care about to see which certificates for those domains show up in the transparency logs. This allows you to see, for example, which certificates out there are currently valid for your domain, assuming the CAs cooperate.

Look for it here: https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/https/ct/

Remember that if you want to *track* a given domain name to be alerted when a certificate is updated, then you should follow the logs directly. This form is useful for doing point-in-time queries, not for generating alerts.

Comment: This is a great answer but leaves the question open as to why on earth Google, doesn't use a cert that is audible? Is this just not available at all yet and Google is putting the indicator in Chrome there to try to get CAs to change?

Comment: @Fraggle Google does something even better. They pins their certs using HSTS, and more impressively, ship their browser (Firefox too) with the correct HSTS entries preloaded. So firefox and chrome won't even ALLOW you to use a fraudulent google certificate, no matter who signed it. The same protection is extended to anyone else who asks.

Comment: @tylerl, Nope. The protection only goes to privileged big boys like Google etc. [It's not a solution that would scale.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security#Limitations) If you had a site `my_site.com` and you tell Google to add `my_site.com` to their preloaded STS list in Chrome, they would simply ignore you. And **even if** STS list is implemented, it still wouldn't stop [the MITM](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63304/how-can-my-employer-be-a-man-in-the-middle-when-i-connect-to-gmail) attacks.

Comment: @Pacerier it really is open to anyone. Here is where you add your site: https://hstspreload.appspot.com

Comment: @Pacerier Sts doesn't stop mitm, but pinning does. And chrome supports pinning via your STS entry.

Comment: @tylerl, Pinning doesn't stop mitm. Pinning only ensures that the browser makes https requests instead of http requests. It's still possible that [those https requests are mitm-ed](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63304/how-can-my-employer-be-a-man-in-the-middle-when-i-connect-to-gmail). Why do you say that pinning stops mitm?

Comment: @Pacerier STS ensures that requests are made over TLS and pinning ensures that only the pinned certificate can be used. Together you're guaranteed that all requests use your designated certificate which makes MITM impossible unless your private key is compromised.

Comment: @tylerl,  You state "chrome **supports** pinning via your STS entry". Please elaborate. As far as I know, STS preloaded lists don't allow you to specify a particular cert.

Comment: @Pacerier Chrome overloads the HSTS functionality to support not only indicating your STS preference, but also to indicate the public keys allowed.

Comment: @tylerl, https://hstspreload.appspot.com/ only has one input box. How would you specify the cert?

Comment: @Pacerier https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Public_Key_Pinning

Comment: *"... a key factor is that the signing behavior of the CA is not auditable"* - audits are *ex post facto* or *reactive*. They are only consulted when there's a known problem. We need a system that's proactive so we can stop issuance before it becomes a problem. Oh wait, [we have that but the browsers abandoned it](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/85272/29925) (and the third party auditor that provided the checks/balances).

Comment: @jww Unfortunately the *Name Constraints* mechanism doesn't really work with the present realities. Any organization that needs to be able to sign xyz.com also typically needs to sign xyz.net and xyz.co.uk. Plus, every existing ca would insist on signing authority over .com, which defeats the purpose of name constraints. The biggest worry is a CA issuing a cert they shouldn't; either for a domain they shouldn't or for a subordinate CA that should't be trusted. This allows that behavior to be monitored real-time by automated systems.

Comment: @tylerl - I don't disagree with you. But those are not technical problems, so they are not our concern. *"Any organization that needs to be able to sign xyz.com also typically needs to sign xyz.net and xyz.co.uk"* - yep, that's the constraint. When I asked why Mozilla did not require it of the subordinate CAs issued to organizations, they told me the CAs told them it was effectively "too much work". Then I asked "how much work is it" and no one could answer. Browser security is such a joke... Worse, its polluting non-borwser user agents and other software.

Comment: @tylerl - *"Plus, every existing ca would insist on signing authority over .com"* - this is slightly different use case. In this use case, the RA is present *and* independent. Hence, there's reduced risk in allowing the trust. But it *might* make sense on ccTLDs since there's a natural administrative boundary present.

Comment: I use Chrome in a corporate environment where they put https traffic through a proxy and use their own certificate. Official browser is IE who wouldn't complain. As of recently, Chrome claims the certificate doesn't have public audit information. Can I somehow manually tell Chrome to trust that specific certificate?

Comment: STS and pinning are 2 different things, with full pinning, the client has baked in a list of domains and a matching fingerprint, so the browser 100% knows that it is wrong if the fingerprint comes back and doesn't match what it already has. Of course this really only works if you control the domains and the client doing the checking (in this case google chrome) and can update it regularly enough to keep those fingerprints correct.

STS just forces you to https, without going through the redirect for all future loads to that domain, this stops some downgrade to http attacks by a mitm.

Answer (score 40):

This is a project by Google called [Certificate Transparency](http://www.certificate-transparency.org/) that attempts to fix flaws with the SSL certificate system.

It essentially has three main goals. (Lifted from http://www.certificate-transparency.org/what-is-ct)

- Make it impossible (or at least very difficult) for a CA to issue a SSL certificate for a domain without the certificate being visible to the owner of that domain.
- Provide an open auditing and monitoring system that lets any domain owner or CA determine whether certificates have been mistakenly or maliciously issued.
- Protect users (as much as possible) from being duped by certificates that were mistakenly or maliciously issued.

Source: http://www.certificate-transparency.org/certificate-transparency-in-chrome

Answer (score 5):

As of January 1, 2015 all EV certificates are required to have public audit records (Signed Certificate Timestamps). The most common way of including these records is through Embedded SCTs. This method includes a new certificate extension/OID (1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2) in the certificate file itself.

For OV and DV certificates, you can request that your CA add your certificates to its CT logs. I know that DigiCert will do this. Eventually, these certificate types will likely also be required to have CT enabled.

In order to have the SCTs embedded, you'll need to reissue any certificate you'd like to have the Public Audit Records after your CA has enabled them for your certs.

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly does it mean when Chrome reports a certificate 'does not have public audit records'?

I think Tyler did a great job of explaining the message and CT, so there's no need in rehashing it.

Based on @Colonel Panic's comment for a test site, here's what the end entity (server) certificate looks ike. Note: you must use TLS 1.0 (or above) and *Server Name Indication* to get the correct certificate. That's the `-servername` option below.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect embed.ct.digicert.com:443 -tls1 -servername embed.ct.digicert.com | \
    openssl x509 -text -noout
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            03:e0:aa:80:19:13:06:8a:28:73:f0:24:29:3e:e4:61
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 13 00:00:00 2014 GMT
            Not After : Nov 18 12:00:00 2015 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=Utah, L=Lehi, O=DigiCert, Inc., CN=embed.ct.digicert.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:9a:64:73:61:53:66:b8:aa:80:c7:cc:53:67:6a:
                    df:da:a9:b1:6a:c5:53:63:55:5f:14:4c:b3:27:d1:
                    3c:e4:0a:1a:e7:16:48:bc:15:46:7e:63:e8:27:3c:
                    c5:28:bd:79:cf:34:d5:9a:67:1e:0c:27:6e:ec:00:
                    5e:69:38:5b:a7:16:4f:b9:09:ec:fc:7e:f2:41:b7:
                    f9:54:f4:6c:c3:22:a6:f5:99:f4:be:9d:64:26:75:
                    9e:b2:b9:16:d7:f5:51:9f:53:ce:74:ca:d6:d6:7a:
                    4a:d4:4d:0e:4d:73:93:30:3c:b9:b8:1d:a0:d8:94:
                    8c:59:7e:82:a4:4c:82:fc:c3:73:7f:b1:56:28:4e:
                    b5:f7:73:53:ac:7b:30:a4:bc:b9:6c:c0:b6:67:0d:
                    19:5e:40:22:11:11:8c:6d:3a:87:47:08:e6:5c:7b:
                    17:7c:64:7a:a1:ff:8c:7c:37:b6:b7:91:2c:c2:90:
                    7e:cc:48:1f:57:1e:f9:db:d4:ac:cf:d9:2b:60:ff:
                    13:2d:88:c5:7e:d8:eb:ec:ed:85:d7:9e:f9:56:32:
                    ca:c1:6b:24:64:9f:63:ba:83:ee:a1:85:4a:e3:ad:
                    45:8c:92:95:3a:e0:80:91:9b:60:b5:75:88:86:4e:
                    0f:81:8c:b5:f4:77:fd:e5:f3:36:f6:33:d6:2b:a0:
                    c4:91
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:0F:80:61:1C:82:31:61:D5:2F:28:E7:8D:46:38:B4:2C:E1:C6:D9:E2

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                88:4F:83:16:87:AD:AE:1E:FF:04:4A:79:66:92:C6:9F:62:69:4F:B1
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:embed.ct.digicert.com
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl3.digicert.com/ssca-sha2-g3.crl

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl4.digicert.com/ssca-sha2-g3.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.16.840.1.114412.1.1
                  CPS: https://www.digicert.com/CPS

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.digicert.com
                CA Issuers - URI:http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            CT Precertificate SCTs: 
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1(0)
                    Log ID    : A4:B9:09:90:B4:18:58:14:87:BB:13:A2:CC:67:70:0A:
                                3C:35:98:04:F9:1B:DF:B8:E3:77:CD:0E:C8:0D:DC:10
                    Timestamp : Nov 13 16:57:03.632 2014 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:45:02:20:06:14:6A:E3:6D:0F:84:5D:6A:98:E7:29:
                                94:80:8B:F2:A4:23:85:68:4E:F9:BC:50:7C:FF:7B:94:
                                EB:20:54:82:02:21:00:91:63:83:FD:F6:31:5E:38:08:
                                AF:A7:5E:00:B7:0B:9B:1F:8B:FD:4D:7E:49:3C:43:E6:
                                64:E5:4B:F9:60:D7:89
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1(0)
                    Log ID    : 68:F6:98:F8:1F:64:82:BE:3A:8C:EE:B9:28:1D:4C:FC:
                                71:51:5D:67:93:D4:44:D1:0A:67:AC:BB:4F:4F:FB:C4
                    Timestamp : Nov 13 16:57:03.619 2014 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:45:02:20:61:4F:69:89:80:6A:62:2D:8E:A2:D0:24:
                                A5:E2:1D:74:67:51:77:C1:9B:DE:99:DE:16:56:2B:02:
                                77:A8:25:49:02:21:00:D3:41:6C:5D:88:40:F0:7A:FE:
                                E0:25:09:86:71:63:86:49:54:DD:96:E4:B5:9B:4A:84:
                                65:A9:25:12:F1:B7:E0
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         62:0c:d1:51:08:8a:a3:d1:df:bc:53:ba:e9:58:67:41:ea:5f:
         e3:51:f2:0b:9d:24:b4:77:6a:cf:96:ff:c5:ce:1c:55:1e:77:
         8a:49:46:7d:19:ef:52:4f:d3:24:b1:f2:95:60:67:40:d4:d1:
         f4:27:e4:66:55:45:c6:a5:51:a6:87:d0:09:af:f6:48:9b:df:
         24:c9:28:ad:47:b9:f6:a3:86:cb:64:64:3d:90:92:0e:94:f7:
         d2:8b:d6:79:b4:df:f2:3f:f5:6e:ea:08:b3:b0:37:87:a3:30:
         a7:f1:db:b7:86:b2:39:64:35:93:ee:5f:7b:01:51:5f:b1:e1:
         e0:d1:5d:a6:e6:a3:53:3f:66:97:16:8f:18:c4:fa:fc:8e:85:
         79:a1:95:7b:69:0b:f5:a4:92:1f:04:cf:ed:f6:95:e3:8f:b4:
         2a:6a:be:0c:a2:b6:53:99:5d:50:78:23:1c:fb:cb:2e:1d:be:
         b5:8d:83:2e:08:96:f8:c9:be:96:13:ed:61:0f:cf:57:44:ff:
         3a:d5:10:b0:bd:08:1f:27:c4:cf:97:17:e8:6a:62:bc:6d:e9:
         64:39:a0:36:79:d6:02:84:b7:47:26:9b:5d:b1:92:aa:f1:36:
         1a:31:9e:27:f2:25:54:89:17:ac:56:54:b0:e0:41:67:e4:b8:
         7b:e0:2c:88
```

Its not clear to me how to actually create one of these things if you are running a private PKI. There's support for the OID in OpenSSL:

```
$ grep -R "1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2" *
crypto/objects/obj_dat.h:951,   /* OBJ_ct_precert_scts    1 3 6 1 4 1 11129 2 4 2 */
crypto/objects/objects.txt:1 3 6 1 4 1 11129 2 4 2  : ct_precert_scts   : CT Precertificate SCTs
```

And:

```
$ grep -R ct_precert_scts *
crypto/objects/obj_dat.h:0x2B,0x06,0x01,0x04,0x01,0xD6,0x79,0x02,0x04,0x02,/* [6191] OBJ_ct_precert_scts */
crypto/objects/obj_dat.h:{"ct_precert_scts","CT Precertificate SCTs",NID_ct_precert_scts,10,
crypto/objects/obj_dat.h:951,   /* "ct_precert_scts" */
crypto/objects/obj_dat.h:951,   /* OBJ_ct_precert_scts    1 3 6 1 4 1 11129 2 4 2 */
crypto/objects/obj_mac.num:ct_precert_scts      951
crypto/objects/objects.txt:1 3 6 1 4 1 11129 2 4 2  : ct_precert_scts   : CT Precertificate SCTs
crypto/x509v3/v3_scts.c:    {NID_ct_precert_scts, 0, NULL,
include/openssl/obj_mac.h:#define SN_ct_precert_scts    "ct_precert_scts"
include/openssl/obj_mac.h:#define LN_ct_precert_scts    "CT Precertificate SCTs"
include/openssl/obj_mac.h:#define NID_ct_precert_scts    951
include/openssl/obj_mac.h:#define OBJ_ct_precert_scts             1L,3L,6L,1L,4L,1L,11129L,2L,4L,2L
```

So there's presentation/display support, but ***NO*** example of how to use it in OpenSSL's self-documenting code. Typically, the self-documentation shows up in the `<openssl src>/apps` directory by way of a feature's use in subcommands.

There's an open question on the OpenSSL mailing list about it: [How to add CT Precertificate SCTs to a server certificate?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mailing.openssl.users/lxS7WWx0cXA/H-5psJIa6C4J).

Comment: Can someone answer this in layman's terms? How do website owners remedy this problem? Do we need to buy a new certificate? If so, where do we get one? All my sites use Register.com SSL certs and ALL of them get this dreaded message scaring customers away!

Comment: Oh, in layman's terms: the bar to entry was just raised. If you are running a private PKI, then you are being corralled into buying a certificate from a participating CA. Participating CAs have to publish certified logs to show that they are issuing certificates for domains they are authorized. Also see the [CT FAQ](http://www.certificate-transparency.org/faq) for the two other ways to comply.

Comment: The problem exists because (1) CAs are not held responsible or accountable; and (2) we've experienced a number of CA failures in the past. The reason CAs are not responsible or accountable is because Browsers and CAs collude at the [CA/Browser Forum](https://cabforum.org/). They make up the rules to suite their taste as they go (yes, the browsers are complicit). Browser security is such a joke...

Comment: Looks like there is no way out of buying the more "expensive" certs, ugh! (this is ridiculous, if CA's are not accountable, then why are we getting raped for cert prices?! What are we paying for?! )

Comment: If you're running a private PKI system, you'd have to spin up your own log server and add a command line flag to Chrome to trust it. Then you'd have to obtain a SCT from said log and then use the TLS extension to send it.